# Enterprise voice with Office 365 plans and Lync 2013

Tags: microsoft-office-365, lync-2013

I am trying to figure out which of the Office 365 plans would be suitable for us. We are a small business (about 20-25 users already) so the "Midsize Business" seems good. However I'm not sure if it supports Lync PSTN connectivity, which is a key requirement. I believe that this is "Enterprise voice" feature?

The first plan that seems to support Enterprise voice is the E3 plan, however it's not clear if that's supported via the Office 365 Lync server, or if we have to set up our own on-premises Lync server to get that connectivity.

So my questions:

1. Can you use "Midsize business" plan and have PSTN connectivity?
2. Does this and/or E3 require an on-premises Lync server?
3. Can SIP trunks be connected to the Online Lync versions? AFAICT they can't

Confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: This is about _functionality_ not licencing

Comment: The REAL answer to this question (which @MichelZ is being helpful) is to simply ask MS, either through call/chat on their Office 365 page or through an O365 partner.  Since it can change over time though, it should be closed.  An answer today of "Yep, E3/E4 plans" could very well be "Yes, to all plans" next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 offers no direct PSTN access, you would need an On-Premise Lync Server for that.^

To answer your questions:

1. Can you use "Midsize business" plan and have PSTN connectivity?

   - I don't think so
2. Does this and/or E3 require an on-premises Lync server?

   - Yes, for Enterprise Voice
3. Can SIP trunks be connected to the Online Lync versions? AFAICT they can't

   - No

Comment: Thanks for clarifying those points: it's quite a complicated product!